Zustand updating only a single item without significant performance issue
I have potentially tens to thousands of Tasks that I'm rendering in Rows, with fields that are always open for editing. The Row isn't super important, just that there are multiple fields with onChange to update the value passed to them.
Below is a small reproduction of my code.
Here's my zustand store:
import { create } from "zustand";
import { immer } from "zustand/middleware/immer";
import { Task } from "./types";

interface WorkspaceState {
  tasks: Record<string, Task>;
  setTasks: (tasks: Record<string, Task>) => void;
  updateTask: (task: Task) => void;
  updateTaskOnChange: <K extends keyof Task>(
    taskId: number,
    key: K,
    value: Task[K]
  ) => void;

  resetAll: VoidFunction;
}

const initialState = {
  tasks: {},
};

export const useWorkspaceState = create<WorkspaceState>()(
  immer((set) => ({
    ...initialState,
    setTasks: (tasks) => set({ tasks }),
    updateTask: (updatedTask) => {
      set((state) => {
        state.tasks[updatedTask.id] = updatedTask;
      });
    },
    updateTaskOnChange: (taskId, key, value) => {
      set((state) => {
        const task = state.tasks[taskId];
        if (task) {
          task[key] = value;
        }
      });
    },
    resetAll: () => {
      set(() => initialState);
    },
  }))
);


Unfortunately, when I update it is extremely slow.
Is there a better way to do this? I want to allow user to inline edit and it should feel fast. Right now it is basically unusable. I'm sure I must be doing something wrong.
Here is the working code - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/59hhsk

try adding a debounce on the handleFieldChange function

Actually the issue turned out to be a context I'm using in that component. Unfortunately the actual code I'm working with (not the sandbox) is fairly complex and I'm trying to refactor it with zustand. Tracking that problematic context down and moving that into its own zustand store resolved the issue.
Thanks, cheers!
